# My ipfs node have zero peers connected, when i am connected to my home network 0 peers and with cellular data to my computer the node works fine

Tags: ipfs

My ipfs node can't connect to other peers, i have the latest go-ipfs 0.8.0 and ipfs desktop 0.15.0, peers count is zero.

My ipfs node have zero peers connected, when i am connected to my home network 0 peers and with cellular data to my computer the node works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you've been bitten by [go-ipfs#8120](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/8120).

Currently the solution is simply to do these steps to get peering rolling again. In IPFS Desktop:

1. Select peers on the left sidebar
2. Select "+ Add Connection" in the upper-right corner
3. In the popup field paste the following: `/ip4/149.56.89.144/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWDiybBBYDvEEJQmNEp1yJeTgVr6mMgxqDrm9Gi8AKeNww`

That will add a peer to the peer table and allow the IPFS daemon to start properly with a swarm of peer connections.

Credits to [ppmSilver](https://discuss.ipfs.io/u/ppmSilver) for [the answer](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/go-ipfs-no-peer-connections/11206/4?u=discordian).